# Why does django show me existing rows error?

Tags: python, django

You are trying to add the field 'created' with 'auto_now_add=True' to user without a default; the database needs something to populate existing rows.

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: `auto_now_add` will only populate the column when the row is being inserted. If it's an existing row the value will be `null` therefore it won't work with a non-null column. I believe instead of using `auto_now_add` you can use `default=timezone.now` (without parentheses!) to work around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when makemigration you will get to option
choose #1 then write
`timezone.now`